# python client and socketIO 2.0.3 serverside

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, websocket, socket.io

I ran into the problem that all libraries for python socketio were dead and and do not support protocol 2.x. Like socketio-client or socketio-client-2 dont work...
is there a working solution?

Столкнулся с проблемой, что все библиотеки устарели и не поддерживают протокол 2.x

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio
Miguel is a serious developer and I'm sure this library is well-maintained.
Also, read through this excellent tutorial on this topic which uses that library: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

Answer (score 0):

The [socketIO_client_nexus](https://github.com/nexus-devs/socketIO-client-2.0.3) Python library is compatible with socket.io 2.x.